# Drupal: show sub-menu in a different block as the parent menu

Tags: drupal

I'd like to display the sub-menu of menu xyz in a different block.

e.g. xyz is the header menu and it's children are placed in the left sidebar.

Any idea how that works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you want the [menu block module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block)

Comment: Alright, that's what i needed... but is there a version that works with all menus... this one apparently only works with primary and secondary menus

Comment: True. That module is awesome.